# Uber Oauth token fails in angular

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, uber-api

I am trying to hit the uber authorization and get the token, but getting below error

> POST https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token 401
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.
>
> angular-oauth2-oidc-codeflow.js:701 Error getting token

I'm using angular 8
"angular-oauth2-oidc-codeflow": "^4.0.1"
for uber auth - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-oauth2-oidc-codeflow

Comment: I have formatted the code and removed the thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to just add the extension in google chrome to allow access using CORS.

(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi...)